# how to compare image with button image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to comparing image with button images but my code is not working for this requirement. What did I do here wrong? Please help me.

```
NSString *btnImage;
UIButton *  sharebutton;

btnImage = @"arrow.png";
    [sharebutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: btnImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if ([sharebutton.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]])
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"else");
    }
```

Comment: why you are not compare both image name Directly

Comment: what are you gonna to solve using that comparison? bet there are better ways to resolve this if statement

Answer (score 2):

you can check image for specific state

```
if([[sharebutton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]])
{
    //Image found
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sharebutton.currentImage == UIImage(named: "arrow.png")) {

}
```

U will need to convert this into obj-c but i think u will get it. :)

Comment: this is objc converted code.....`if ([[buttonname currentImage] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"]]){
     }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(firstImage) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(secondImage)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare button image with another image name then set your button image this way:

```
sharebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Remember one thing here don't set background image for button.

Now you can compare button image with another image this way:

```
if (sharebutton.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "arrow.png")) != nil)  {
    println("YES")
} else {
    println("NO")
}
```

Comment: the question was in Obj-C, no?

Comment: When he asked a question it has a swift tag but now it is edited with obj-c tag..:) @slxl

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [sharebutton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
if ([image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]]) {

}
```

Do this,you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i'm using:

```
NSData *leftImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([sharebutton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]);

//take note that using `imageForState:` only works if you set your image using `setImage:forState:`
//if you are using `setBackgroundImage:forState:`, `[shareButton currentBackgroundImage]` is what you need.

NSData *rightImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]);

if ([leftImageData isEqualToData:rightImageData])
{
    //same
}
else
{
    //not same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons I'd compare the file names rather than creating a temporary image which is much more expensive

```
NSString *btnImage;
UIButton *sharebutton;


btnImage = @"arrow.png";
[sharebutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: btnImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if ([btnImage isEqualToString:@"arrow.png"])
  {
    NSLog(@"ok");
  }
else
  {
    NSLog(@"else");
  }
```

Of course this requires to maintain the variable `btnImage` to hold always the current file name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIButton *sharebutton;
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@“arrow.png"];
[sharebutton setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if (sharebutton.currentImage == [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"])
{
    //do something here
}
```